# How do I get googlebot to see ajax content

Tags: ajax, post, googlebot

Can I somehow easy get googlebot to see this ajax content? Using post ajax method:

Calling page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body onload="getTest(1)">
<div id="txtHint"></div>        
<script type="text/javascript">
function getTest(page)
{
    var parameters = "";
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    parameters = parameters + "page="+page;
    xmlhttp.open("POST","ajaxtest.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(parameters);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

ajaxtest.php:

```
<?php
    $page=$_POST["page"];
    echo "This is page number $page <br />";
    echo "<a href='javascript:getTest(2);'>Link to page 2</a>"; 
?>
```

This is just what i want and it works. The navigation is generated in the ajax call. Only problem is that Google cant see it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google explains exactly how to do it](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html). FYI, using Ajax or JavaScript in general to generate your content is [a really bad idea](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="txtHint"><?php include 'ajaxtest.php'; ?></div>
```

doesn't solve your issue?